# How to check which update installed on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I read this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx) and installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and found out that the latest update version is 5. I'm wondering is it possible somehow to check which update number currently installed?

I checked `Help`-> `About Microsoft Visual Studio`, but it doesn't give much information.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The About page *does* display this information in the Version number. 12.0.21005.1 REL is the release version. Update 5 is 12.0.40629.0:

[image: About dialog box]

In fact, you don't need to check the version. You can have Visual Studio check for any updates itself by going to *Tools > Extensions & Updates > Updates > Product Updates*. If an update is needed it will appear there.

Comment: The up-vote was for the Instructions on HOW to get  VS to apply the latest update. Excellent job of answering the un-asked but intended question.

Comment: VS 2015 and 2017 display a warning flag on the upper right corner of the window.